# Copying selected directory and file using contents in the text file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a directory with some entries. One is a folder (`Time`) with a su directory and the other one is a text files `1.txt` with paths of another folder which looks like

```
*Time/Inspire/config/dashboards/non.json
*Time/Inspire/config/dashboards/job.json
```

I want to create a folder or zip and copy those files into it.

Expected outcome should be a new Folder with `Time` (parent) folder and its subdirectory and the end file (`non.json` and `job.json`) such has `Inspire/Config/dashboard/non.json` and `job.json`.

Code I have right now:

```
mkdir try
 sed 's/^\*//' difference.txt > rah.txt
 xargs -a rah.txt mv -t /c/Users/name/Downloads/try/
```

Unfortunately it only gets end file, not the folder paths.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
tar -c -f - -T <(sed 's/^\*//' 1.txt) | (mkdir diff && cd diff/ && tar xf -)
```

Comment: $ tar -c -f - -T <(sed 's/^\*//' difference.txt) | (mkdir name && cd name/ && tar xf -)
tar: /dev/fd/63: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

...sadly no :(

Comment: @ Shawn i mange to get files but unfortunately not the folder that leads to the file